# How to fix scroll problem when the modal dialog is show up?

Tags: c#, jquery

when I show up my modal dialog popup (after a click on a button), the scroll-bar in the background scroll-down and idk why.

I've already tried some css modification like this one 
    $('body').css('overflow', 'inherit')
and I've also tried 
    window.scrollTo(0,0)

```
<div 
class="modal fade" id="PopUpModificaPOS" role="dialog" 
    style="display:none">
    <div class="modal-dialog" style="width:100%" id="divPopupMod">
        <% Html.RenderPartial("Partial/PopUpModificaPOS", Model); %>
    </div>
</div>

//after a click on a button,this button call 
function showPopUpModificaPOS(){
   $("#PopUpModificaPOS").dialog({ 
     height: 325,
     width: 500,
     modal: true, 
     position: "absolute" }).dialog("widget")
.position({ my: "top", at: "top", of: window });
}
```

I expect the scroll-bar must not scroll-down.

Comment: you need to have body overflow hidden not inherit - and then when the modal is closed, reset the overflow to auto

Comment: its most likely the `position: absolute` modal dialogs usually have `positions: fixed`

Comment: Still not working with these both solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem changing the way I build the popup.

```
<script id="modificaTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template">
<form class='formPopUpPos' id='formModifica'>   
   //put here your popup layout
</form>
</script>

//then call the script
function showpopup(){
    var template = kendo.template($("#modificaTemplate").html());
    var result = template();//pass here your parameters if u have someone
    $("#popupKendoDialog").html(template);
    var popupModificaPOS = creazioneDelPopupDialog();
    popupModificaPOS.dialog({ title: 'Modifica dispositivo POS' });
    popupModificaPOS.dialog({ width: '500' });
    popupModificaPOS.dialog('open');
}

function creazioneDelPopupDialog() {
    var popupRegistrazionePOS = $("#popupKendoDialog").dialog({            
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 'auto',
        width: 'auto',
        position: { my: "center top", at: "center top", of: window },
        modal: true,
        open: function () {
            $(".formPopUpPos").css({ "color": "#4d4d4d" });
            $(".formPopUpPos").css({ "font-family": "inherit" });
            $(".formPopUpPos").css({ "font-size": 12 });
        }
    });
    return popupRegistrazionePOS;
}
```

I still dk why doens't work in the other way.